# web2py - Choose DB

Tags: python, web2py

I have two DB (Oracle and MSSQL) with the same Tables. It's possible to Choose one of those DB when logging into the Application.

**view.html**

```html
<form action="{{=URL('test?dbs=')}}">
    <label for="dbs">Choose a DB:</label>
    <select name="dbs">
      <option value="oracle">Oracle</option>
      <option value="mssql">MSSQL</option>    
    </select> 
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

{{=db_choose}}
```

**controller.py**

```py
def test():
    db_choose = request.vars.dbs
    if db_choose == "oracle":
        db = DAL('oracle://username/password@test')
        return dict(db_choose = db)
    elif db_choose == "mssql":
        db = DAL('mssql://username:password@localhost/test')
        return dict(db_choose = db_choose)
    else:
        return dict(db_choose = db_choose)
    return dict(db_choose = db_choose)
```

Comment: What is exactly your question?

Comment: I want to choose one of two DB to use in my application, but how can i overwrite the `db.py` (db variable) configuration from the controller and view?

Comment: Please clarify your question, it doesn't seem to focus enough to understand what do you want to achieve. Try to add an introduction to the problem (why are you doing this?), explain what have you tried and include details about the errors/unexpected behaviour that you have found so far, explain what do you expect? (what do you want to achieve?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to persist the choice from request to request, so maybe store the choice in the session.

In a model file (e.g., db.py):

```
db = DAL('oracle://username/password@test' if session.db == 'oracle' \
         else 'mssql://username:password@localhost/test')
```

In the controller:

```
def test():
    session.db = request.vars.dbs or 'mssql'
    return dict(db_choose = session.db)
```

If you want the choice to persist beyond a single session, consider storing each user's choice in their `auth_user` record (if there is a login), or storing it in `localStorage` in the browser.